# Why do I have to run 'bundle install' after every rails project I create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Everytime I create a new rails project I have to run `bundle install` at the end. I know for a fact that not everybody need to do this.

Do you know any way I can avoid this step? It does take some time to complete...

Thanks.

Comment: How many new Rails projects do you create so that this is a big deal?

Comment: You should really use bundle, it solves almost any dependency issues you might have.

Comment: @DaveNewton: that's not really the point. I asked why and for a solution. Please contribute to that if you please. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bundle install` prepares a fixed set of gems for your application, which has all the dependencies and versions resolved. It stores the result in a file called `Gemfile.lock`.

You **have** to update the `Gemfile.lock` after modifying `Gemfile`, in this case you **have** to create it with `bundle install` after generating the app.

You don't have to run `bundle install` only if you're not using Bundler, which is only possible with Rails 2.3.

Comment: Although you *can* [use Bundler with Rails 2.3](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html).

Comment: so what you are saying is that i can only avoid this step if I use rails 2.3 or before?

Comment: @Dave, and you *should* - makes life much easier.

Comment: @nunos, yes. Which means you can't avoid it. Anyways, [Bundler 1.1 is promised to be much faster](http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/10/14/why-bundler-1-1-will-be-much-faster).